# node.js - Are we allowed to pass in a var defined as a string to a parameter of a function that requires a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, parameters

so I have this method:

```
    module.exports = {
    scanDirectory: function() {
        walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
            files.push(stat.name);
            console.log(files[i]);
            next();
            i++;
            //console.log('The number of items in the array is: ' + files.length);
        });
        return files;
    },
    readFiles: function(name) {
        var text = fs.readFileSync('./views/index.jade', 'utf8');
        return text;
    }
};
```

The first part scans the directory and returns the files in the directory. (Assume the first function works) - which it does to a degree when I run the program, but this is just a reference..

For the second function, I would like it to read in the files from the file[i] array instead of specifically specifying

```
> './views/index.jade'
```

I was wondering if this is possible...like to clarify, instead of

```
> readFileSync('./views/blah.txt', 'utf8');...
```

I want something like...

```
for(i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
   var text = fs.readFileSync(file[i], 'utf8');
   return text;
}
```

If something like this is possible, please guide me how to or point me in the right direction.

Much appreciated, thanks,
Brian

Comment: You cannot pass vars. By using the variable (in your case the object property reference `file[i]`), you *do pass the string* which the variable references. There is no difference for the function.

Comment: Of course it is possible, does your script not work? It looks fine apart from the `return` statement in the loop. What do you expect the function to do with `files` which it does not do?

Comment: If I use files[i], like in the function readFileSync(files[i], 'utf8'); does not work for me because I get a TypeError: path must be a string.

Comment: check out the value of files[i]: `console.log(JSON.stringify(files[i]))` or `console.log(typeof files[i])`

Comment: I'll do that right when I get back on my laptop. I have a followup question though, the way I expressed my module.exports..  Does it mean if I were to run these functions say on another file app.js, would I have to run scan directory() before read files()? Since files[i] would be empty if I don't run the functions in said order? Or am I not understanding this scope concept?...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible. If it isn't working than you need to figure out a few things:

What is the value of file[i], does file[i] have the correct permissions, does file[i] exist, what is the value of text.

Somewhere in there you will see something that doesn't quite add up.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thanks for your response.. I was wondering if it's possible to call files[i].toString() as a parameter, and if I do, how do I actually grab files[i].. since the array is populated from another method.